# access vbs file passing parameters comes empty form

Tags: vbscript

i am creating a .vbs file that should open access, and inside access a form call "Issue Details", but passing a parameter, meaning that if i have 10 issues in my "Issues" table a vbs file is created for each one and when clicked should open the right form id(would be one ID for each in the table). It is so far opening access and it is opening the form(Issue Details) but it is blank. What am i missing? Help, getting crazy here ... Check code below

```
Public Sub sendMRBmail(mrbid)
Dim tmprs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database 
Set db = CurrentDb
Set tmprs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from Issues where [ID] = " & mrbid)
If IsNull(tmprs) Then
MsgBox "Record is not yet available"
Else
DoCmd.OpenForm "Issue Details", , , "[ID] = " & mrbid
End If
Set tmprs = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Create_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_Command48_Click

Dim snid As Integer
snid = Me.ID

Dim filename As String
filename = "S:\Quality Control\vbs\QC" & snid & ".vbs" 

Dim proc As String
proc = Chr(34) & "sendMRBmail" & Chr(34)

Dim strList As String

strList = "On Error Resume Next" & vbNewLine
strList = strList & "dim accessApp" & vbNewLine
strList = strList & "set accessApp = createObject(" & Chr(34) & "Access.Application" & Chr(34)")" & vbNewLine
strList = strList & "accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase(" & Chr(34) & "S:\Quality Control\Quality DB\Quality Database.accdb" & Chr(34) & ")" & vbNewLine
strList = strList & "accessApp.Run " & proc & "," & Chr(34) & snid & Chr(34) & vbNewLine
 strList = strList & "set accessApp = nothing" & vbNewLine

Open filename For Output As #1
Print #1, strList
Close #1

Err_Command48_Click:

 If Err.Number <> 0 Then

 MsgBox "Email Error #: " & Err.Number & ", " & "Description: " & Err.Description
      Exit Sub

 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this the entire code? I would expect an Scripting.Filesystem object to write the snid vbs file, as well as a `ExecuteGlobal` command to activate the vbs you created in strList.

Comment: I am not sure about that, i edited it and added the Open, Print, Close that was on my original code, but nothing else. Am i missing code? It does create the vbs file, and it does work since it opens the form, but empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer. I added acFormEdit at the end of my DoCmd and it worked, check below:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Issue Details", , , "[ID] = " & mrbid, acFormEdit
```